# Select MySQL records that conflict with a proposed unique index

Tags: mysql, sql, select, unique-index

I have a set of records that I want to add a unique index to, however some existing records conflict with that index, so I want to identify them and remove them in order that the constraint can be placed on the data.

Is there a way I can write a SELECT query based around any record that contradicts the unique index?

Example:

Table has columns

id | user | question_id | response | is_current

I want a unique index such that

user | question_id | response |is_current

is not duplicated.

Is it possible to SELECT all records where that set of values is not unique?

Comment: select distinct user,question_id,response,is_current from tablename

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### Show non-unique:

```
select user,question_id,response,is_current,count(*) as theCount 
from tablename 
group by user,question_id,response,is_current
having theCount>1
```

Comment: if you want to know how to auto jam them in a new table, I will do that too. Of course I would need some guidance on how you want the id to be finalized